# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString not working perfectly for Arabic numbers

Tags: ios, nsstring, nslocale

Its not replacing comma, in case of Arabic language.

```
    NSString *strAfterReplacingComma = @"٢٠٠٫٠٠";//100.00
    NSString *strAfterReplacing = [strAfterReplacingComma  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];

    NSLog(@"%@", strAfterReplacing);
```

Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Comment: I checked your code and its working fine and able to replace comma (,) into dot(.) please explain actual requirement in detail.

Comment: what is the output of `NSLog(@"%@", strAfterReplacing);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma in your Arabic text (٫) has a unicode number `U+002C`. It is the arabic decimal separator. Not a comma. The english Comma(,) has a unicode number `U+066B`. Hence the replace fails.

Use this `٫` instead of `,` in you `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`.

Comment: An ASCII comma is `0x2C` so I assume it's the Arabic separator that is `U+066B`

Comment: The one used in the strAfterReplacingComma and the one used in stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString are two different characters. They have two different unicodes. So the replace doesn't occur. U+002C is used in the original string. Where as U+066B is being used in stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString. Check this link for the difference between these two: http://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html

Comment: ASCII comma 0x2C is unicode U+002C. It is not U+006B

Comment: Thanks Shanti K. Can you please tell me, how can I replace it using unicodes. Can you give me some sample codes for this ?

Comment: Prajnaranjan.. In your case.. Just replace the argument for stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString.. You don't have to use unicode.. You can directly copy the arabic decimal separator comma from the arabic text.. and place it as an argument in the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString..